# Invoking soap web service via spring boot fails with Un-authorized 401 exception

Tags: spring-boot, soap, jaxb

I am trying to invoke a secured soap web service via spring boot application.

However, when I am trying to do so, I keep getting the following exception always despite passing the required credentials.

```
{
    "timestamp": "2020-02-02T17:17:09.081+0000",
    "status": 500,
    "error": "Internal Server Error",
    "message": "Unauthorized [401]",
    "trace": "org.springframework.ws.client.WebServiceTransportException: Unauthorized [401]\n\tat org.springframework.ws.client.core.WebServiceTemplate.handleError(WebServiceTemplate.java:699)\n\tat org.springframework.ws.client.core.WebServiceTemplate.doSendAndReceive(WebServiceTemplate.java:609)\n\tat org.springframework.ws.client.core.WebServiceTemplate.sendAndReceive(WebServiceTemplate.java:555)\n\tat org.springframework.ws.client.core.WebServiceTemplate.marshalSendAndReceive(WebServiceTemplate.java:390)\n\tat org.springframework.ws.client.core.WebServiceTemplate.marshalSendAndReceive(WebServiceTemplate.java:378)\n\tat com.app.oracle.doo.ominvoker.client.SoapClient.createOrder(SoapClient.java:30)\n\tat com.app.oracle.doo.ominvoker.controller.OrderImportController.createOrder(OrderImportController.java:55)\n\tat sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)\n\tat sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)\n\tat sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)\n\tat java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)\n\tat org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:190)\n\tat org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:138)\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:106)\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:888)\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:793)\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87)\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1040)\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:943)\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006)\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:909)\n\tat javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:660)\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883)\n\tat javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)\n\tat org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)\n\tat org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100)\n\tat org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)\n\tat org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93)\n\tat org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)\n\tat org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201)\n\tat org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202)\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)\n\tat org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:541)\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139)\n\tat org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74)\n\tat org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)\n\tat org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:367)\n\tat org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)\n\tat org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:860)\n\tat org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1598)\n\tat org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)\n\tat java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)\n\tat java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)\n\tat org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)\n\tat java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)\n",
    "path": "/createOrder"
}
```

I have been able to invoke the same webservice via SOAP tool by providing the same credentials.
I am not sure of the right way to pass the soap header information with the credentials to invoke the webservice.

I referred many threads and found the following way to implement it. However, it still does not work for me.

Any help in this regard would be highly appreciated.

One more point is that while invoking the service via soap tool, I have also set the domain information as oracle/wss11_username_token_with_message_protection_client_policy.

I did not know how to pass this information so set it as one of the property in Connection Request (set in Authentication.java file as mentioned below)

Thanks

pom.xml

```
<dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web-services</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.jvnet.jaxb2.maven2</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jaxb2-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>0.13.2</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>generate</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <args>
                        <arg>-XautoNameResolution</arg>
                    </args>
                    <generatePackage>com.app.oracle.doo.ominvoker.soap.api.orderimport</generatePackage>
                    <generateDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/main/java</generateDirectory>
                    <schemaDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/wsdl</schemaDirectory>
                    <schemaIncludes>
                        <include>*.wsdl</include>
                    </schemaIncludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

SoapConfig.java

```
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.oxm.jaxb.Jaxb2Marshaller;

import com.app.oracle.doo.ominvoker.client.SoapClient;

@Configuration
public class SoapConfig {

    @Bean
    public Jaxb2Marshaller marshaller() {
        Jaxb2Marshaller marshaller = new Jaxb2Marshaller();
        marshaller.setPackagesToScan("com.app.oracle.doo.ominvoker.soap.api.orderimport");
        return marshaller;
    }

    @Bean
    public SoapClient orderImportClient(Jaxb2Marshaller marshaller) {
        SoapClient client = new SoapClient();
        client.setDefaultUri("https://host:port/order/OrderServices");
        client.setMarshaller(marshaller);
        client.setUnmarshaller(marshaller);
        client.setMessageSender(new Authentication("Manager", "Welcome1"));
        return client;
    }

}
```

SoapClient.java

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.oxm.jaxb.Jaxb2Marshaller;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import org.springframework.ws.client.core.WebServiceTemplate;
import org.springframework.ws.client.core.support.WebServiceGatewaySupport;

import com.app.oracle.doo.ominvoker.soap.api.orderimport.CreateOrders;
import com.app.oracle.doo.ominvoker.soap.api.orderimport.CreateOrdersResponse;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

@Service
public class SoapClient extends WebServiceGatewaySupport {

    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(SoapClient.class);

    @Autowired
    private Jaxb2Marshaller marshaller;

    private WebServiceTemplate template;

    public CreateOrdersResponse createOrder(CreateOrders request) {
        template = new WebServiceTemplate(marshaller);
        return (CreateOrdersResponse) template.marshalSendAndReceive("https://host:port/order/OrderServices", request);
    }


}
```

Authentication.java

```
package com.app.oracle.doo.ominvoker.config;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.util.Base64;

import org.springframework.ws.transport.http.HttpUrlConnectionMessageSender;

public class Authentication extends HttpUrlConnectionMessageSender {

    private String username;

    private String password;

    public Authentication() {
    }

    public Authentication(String username, String password) {
        this.username = username;
        this.password = password;
    }

    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    @Override
    protected void prepareConnection(HttpURLConnection connection) throws IOException { 
       String userpassword = username+":"+password;
       String encoded = Base64.getEncoder().withoutPadding().encodeToString(userpassword.getBytes());
       connection.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Basic " + encoded);
       connection.setRequestProperty("domain", "oracle/wss11_username_token_with_message_protection_client_policy"); 
       super.prepareConnection(connection); 
   }

}
```

Comment: Any help / pointers in this would be helpful. Can anyone please help?

Comment: Using Rest with jwt the browser sends an options request to check, if the Authorization header is accepted. You didn't post your websecurity configuration, but that could be the reason it works on the soap tool and not in Browser. Would explain, why you get 401 (auth error) and not 403 (access denied). Had the same problem with rest once, this was the solution for me.

Answer (score 1):

Isn't your WS secured by WS-Security . 
Instead of: `HttpUrlConnectionMessageSender` you should define: `org.springframework.ws.soap.security.wss4j2.Wss4jSecurityInterceptor`

```
@Bean
    public Wss4jSecurityInterceptor securityInterceptor(){
        Wss4jSecurityInterceptor wss4jSecurityInterceptor = new Wss4jSecurityInterceptor();
        wss4jSecurityInterceptor.setSecurementActions("Timestamp UsernameToken");
        wss4jSecurityInterceptor.setSecurementUsername("Manager");
        wss4jSecurityInterceptor.setSecurementPassword("Welcome1");
        return wss4jSecurityInterceptor;
    }
```

And then inject it, into your Soap Client:

```
    ClientInterceptor[] interceptors = new ClientInterceptor[] {securityInterceptor()};
    client.setInterceptors(interceptors);
```